# Testing a random number function in JavaScript with Mocha and Chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, statistics, mocha.js, chai

Suppose I have a function that returns a number multiplied by two.

```
function double(number){
  return number * 2;
}
```

To test it with [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) is easy.

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;

describe("#double", function(){
  it("should double a number", function(){
    expect(double(2)).to.equal(4);
    expect(double(4.5)).to.equal(9);
    expect(double(-3)).to.equal(-6);
  });
});
```

But now suppose I have a function that returns a random integer between two specified integers, call them `min` and `max`.

```
function randBetween(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

I won't be able to predict what the returned value will be equal to. I could write a test that makes sure the returned value is both greater than or equal to `min` and less than or equal to `max`, but that doesn't actually test whether the returned value is *random*. Is there a statistically valid way for me to test whether my `randBetween` function is working?

P.S. I know the function does not handle invalid arguments, e.g. if `max` is less than `min`. Please leave that aside for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't test it with a single call; you'll need a large number of calls to prove randomness (within a reasonable definition of randomness).

In the large number of calls, you'll want to:

1. Make sure it doesn't return values out of range
2. Make sure it does provide random values within a reasonable definition of randomness (given it's a deterministic PRNG)

[This question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411/how-to-test-randomness-case-in-point-shuffling) go into how to do the latter, although sadly the links in the accepted answer are mostly dead now.

The National Institute of Standards and Technology has a whole section dedicated to PRNGs, including [this page describing several tests](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/stats_tests.html) you could use to ensure the randomness of what you get back.

Of course, provided your function is implemented correctly (and it appears to be, if it's meant to return `min <= value < max` as is usually the case), ultimately you're testing the randomness of the underlying `Math.random` implementation.