# Find product of any subset of elements from a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, math

what is the best way to find the product of any number of elements from a list?

e.g if I have `[a,b,c]` as the input, i should get `[a,b,c,a*b,a*c,b*c,a*b*c]` as the output (order of elements for output doesn't matter.)

**PS: Can we do it recursively? (e.g you just need the product of `a*b` and `c` to get the product `a*b*c`.**

Any idea or suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
from itertools import combinations

l = [2, 3, 5]

result = []
for i in range(1, len(l) + 1):
    result += list(combinations(l, i))

multiplied_result = [reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, lst) for lst in result]
```

Now if we print the result, we get

```
>>> print listmap
[2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, is this method the fastest way that you know so far?

Comment: @freak_warrior Yes. Kasra's answer does the same within a single list comprehension.

Comment: Ok, what I meant is an algorithm which can do the same in less complexity, like for this case... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680548/given-an-array-of-numbers-return-array-of-products-of-all-other-numbers-no-div

Comment: @freak_warrior Oh Ok. I think that maybe you ought to ask it as a different question under the algorithms tag then..

Comment: @freak_warrior Were you able to resolve this? If my answer helped, don't forget to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations` within a list comprehension :

```
>>> def find_mul(li):
...      return [[reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,j) for j in combinations(li,i)] for i in xrange(2,len(li)+1)]
...
```

DEMO:

```
>>> [list(combinations([2,3,4],i)) for i in xrange(2,len([2,3,4])+1)]
[[(2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)], [(2, 3, 4)]]
>>> l=[2,3,4]
>>> find_mul(l)
[[6, 8, 12], [24]]
```