# Given an array of numbers, return array of products of all other numbers (no division)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was asked this question in a job interview, and I'd like to know how others would solve it. I'm most comfortable with Java, but solutions in other languages are welcome.

> Given an array of numbers, `nums`, return an array of numbers `products`, where `products[i]` is the product of all `nums[j], j != i`.
>
> ```
> Input : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> Output: [(2*3*4*5), (1*3*4*5), (1*2*4*5), (1*2*3*5), (1*2*3*4)]
>       = [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]
> ```
>
> You must do this in `O(N)` without using division.

Comment: This question has come up a few times in the last week or so; are you all interviewing with the same company? :)

Comment: I'm currently browsing `[interview-questions]` tag looking for it. Do you have a link if you've found it?

Comment: Here's one from yesterday; there's been a couple in different forms, but I don't think they were tagged as interviews: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669831/finding-the-product-of-each-of-the-n-1-subsets-of-a-given-array

Comment: @Michael: That question allows division. Mine explicitly forbids it. I'd say they're two different questions.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215/interesting-interview-questions

Comment: Substitute division with log(a/b)=log(a)-log(b) and voila!

Comment: imagine if there are 1 or more than 1 zeros in the array, how will you handle the case??

Comment: I provided a solution of O(n) space and O(n^2) time complexity that you may have a look

Comment: int[] arr = new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5};                                                                                            int sum =1;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            sum = sum*arr[i];
        }

        int finalArray[] = new int[arr.length];

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            finalArray[i] = sum/arr[i];
        }

        IntStream.of(finalArray).forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: (@SarojKumarSahoo: how is `sum/arr[i]` `without using division`?)

Answer (score 287, accepted):

An explanation of [polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276101/polygenelubricants) method is:

The trick is to construct the arrays (in the case for 4 elements):

```cpp
{              1,         a[0],    a[0]*a[1],    a[0]*a[1]*a[2],  }
{ a[1]*a[2]*a[3],    a[2]*a[3],         a[3],                 1,  }
```

Both of which can be done in O(n) by starting at the left and right edges respectively.

Then, multiplying the two arrays element-by-element gives the required result.

My code would look something like this:

```cpp
int a[N] // This is the input
int products_below[N];
int p = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    products_below[i] = p;
    p *= a[i];
}

int products_above[N];
p = 1;
for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    products_above[i] = p;
    p *= a[i];
}

int products[N]; // This is the result
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    products[i] = products_below[i] * products_above[i];
}
```

If you need the solution be O(1) in space as well, you can do this (which is less clear in my opinion):

```cpp
int a[N] // This is the input
int products[N];

// Get the products below the current index
int p = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    products[i] = p;
    p *= a[i];
}

// Get the products above the current index
p = 1;
for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    products[i] *= p;
    p *= a[i];
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the prefix/suffix combo that I did; I'm just wondering if there's a simpler solution that I've missed.

Comment: This is O(n) runtime but it's also O(n) in space complexity. You can do it in O(1) space. I mean, other than the size of the input and output containers of course.

Comment: @wilhelmtell Agreed. Have added a simple modification of the algorithm to be O(1) in space.

Comment: Very clever! Is there a name for this algorithm?

Comment: I don't know of a name for the algorithm, sorry.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Great work man, But please tell me the main logic behind this and how did you start this once you get the requirement.

Comment: @A.C.Balaji It all kinda falls out after you do that split into two separate arrays. The second case does the same work, but is tweaked to store results directly into the products array. Is there some other aspect of this that I could clarify for you?

Comment: Algorithm will fail if any one of the element is 0. So don't forgot to check the 0 to skip.

Comment: @Mani The algorithm is fine if there are elements set to 0. However it may be possible to scan the input for such elements and be more efficient if they are found. If there are two zero elements, the entire result is zero, and if there is only one, say `v_i=0` then the only non zero entry in the result is the ith element. However I suspect that adding a pass to detect and count the zero elements would detract from the clarity of the solution, and probably not make any real performance gain in the majority of cases..

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Thanks for the clarification. It worked perfectly as you mentioned. perfect. Though is it lagging to handle overflow ?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I am not trying to find the faults, but mostly these kind of questions asked in interview and interviewer will catch these questions, so it would be benefit to the readers like me to mention as   assumptions exp int[] a = { 12345, 163633, 636362, 363630 };

Comment: @MichaelAnderson And to be honest , this is the perfect solution i have found across web so far..

Comment: @Mani it will only overflow if one of the results would overflow. Each product is constructed only from the terms it should contain - no division is performed.

Comment: Hi, can we extend this to find the product of all elements in any subset of an array?

Comment: @freak_warrior If you want the result to be an array containing all the possible products of the elements, you're better off using a simple recursive style method - but the array size can grow quickly. In general it would contain `2^n` elements where `n` is the input array length. If that's not what you meant, maybe you could clarify your requirements.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: Yes that's what I wanted. Can you describe the algo?

Comment: @freak_warrior Start with a set containing just the value 1. Take the next value in your input array cal it v. Copy the set, but scale each value by v, then add them all back into your set. Repeat until you've gone through the input array. Of course if you're working in C you can use a raw sorted array as your set, you then merge-sort with the scaled "copy" - (but no need to really make a copy, just maintain two iterators into the same array ... need to be careful about negative values though....)

Comment: Terrific. @MichaelAnderson where did you draw inspiration for the clever solution?

Comment: Can be done easily using log, like [this solution](http://abhisheknirmal.blogspot.com/2016/06/java-program-to-calculate-array-of.html).

Comment: @nickspol fails with negative numbers.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Isn't this solution still O(n) space since the size of the products array changes when N changes?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen It's O(1) in _extra_ space. The `products` array is the output, and `a` is the output array. Its clearly impossible to get something O(1) in total space (including input and output) if the input and output are size `O(n)`.

Comment: lovely answer!!

Answer (score 54):

Here is a small recursive function (in C++) to do the modification in-place. It requires O(n) extra space (on stack) though. Assuming the array is in `a` and `N` holds the array length, we have:

```cpp
int multiply(int *a, int fwdProduct, int indx) {
    int revProduct = 1;
    if (indx < N) {
       revProduct = multiply(a, fwdProduct*a[indx], indx+1);
       int cur = a[indx];
       a[indx] = fwdProduct * revProduct;
       revProduct *= cur;
    }
    return revProduct;
}
```

Comment: Could anyone explain this recursion?

Comment: @nikhil It does recursion first, remembering the intermediate products , eventually forming the number product for `num[N-1]`; then on the way back it calculates the second part of the multiplication which is then used to modify the number array in place.

Comment: imagine if there are 1 or more than 1 zeros in the array, how will you handle the case??

Answer (score 20):

Here's my attempt to solve it in Java. Apologies for the non-standard formatting, but the code has a lot of duplication, and this is the best I can do to make it readable.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Products {
    static int[] products(int... nums) {
        final int N = nums.length;
        int[] prods = new int[N];
        Arrays.fill(prods, 1);
        for (int
           i = 0, pi = 1    ,  j = N-1, pj = 1  ;
           (i < N)         && (j >= 0)          ;
           pi *= nums[i++]  ,  pj *= nums[j--]  )
        {
           prods[i] *= pi   ;  prods[j] *= pj   ;
        }
        return prods;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
            Arrays.toString(products(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
        ); // prints "[120, 60, 40, 30, 24]"
    }
}
```

The loop invariants are `pi = nums[0] * nums[1] *.. nums[i-1]` and `pj = nums[N-1] * nums[N-2] *.. nums[j+1]`. The `i` part on the left is the "prefix" logic, and the `j` part on the right is the "suffix" logic.

---

#### Recursive one-liner

[Jasmeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680548/interview-q-given-an-array-of-numbers-return-array-of-products-of-all-other-num/2696005#2696005) gave a (beautiful!) recursive solution; I've turned it into this (hideous!) Java one-liner. It does *in-place modification*, with `O(N)` temporary space in the stack.

```scala
static int multiply(int[] nums, int p, int n) {
    return (n == nums.length) ? 1
      : nums[n] * (p = multiply(nums, nums[n] * (nums[n] = p), n + 1))
          + 0*(nums[n] *= p);
}

int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
multiply(arr, 1, 0);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// prints "[120, 60, 40, 30, 24]"
```

Comment: I think the 2-variables loop makes it harder to understand than necessary (at least for my poor brain!), two separate loops would do the job as well.

Comment: That's why I separated the code into left/right, in an effort to show that the two are independent of each other. I'm not sure if that actually works, though =)

Comment: `the code has a lot of duplication` nah. The problem has a notable amount of *symmetry*, highlighted by your a approach and formatting.

Answer (score 15):

Translating Michael Anderson's solution into Haskell:

```hs
otherProducts xs = zipWith (*) below above

     where below = scanl (*) 1 $ init xs

           above = tail $ scanr (*) 1 xs
```

Answer (score 13):

Sneakily circumventing the "no divisions" rule:

```py
sum = 0.0
for i in range(a):
  sum += log(a[i])

for i in range(a):
  output[i] = exp(sum - log(a[i]))
```

Comment: Nitpick: as far as I'm aware, computers implement logarithms using their binomial expansion - which *does* require division...

Answer (score 10):

Here you go, simple and clean solution with O(N) complexity:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] r = new int[a.length];
    int x = 1;
    r[0] = 1;
    for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
        r[i]=r[i-1]*a[i-1];
    }
    for (int i=a.length-1;i>0;i--){
        x=x*a[i];
        r[i-1]=x*r[i-1];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<r.length;i++){
        System.out.println(r[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Could you care to write explanations? It could earn you more votes if code made sense from the first glance. Explain the science.

Answer (score 8):

1. Travel Left->Right and keep saving product. Call it Past. -> O(n)
2. Travel Right -> left keep the product. Call it Future. -> O(n)
3. Result[i] = Past[i-1] * future[i+1] -> O(n)
4. Past[-1] = 1; and Future[n+1]=1;

O(n)

Comment: Plus one, for focussing on us learning the science.

Answer (score 6):

C++, O(n):

```
long long prod = accumulate(in.begin(), in.end(), 1LL, multiplies<int>());
transform(in.begin(), in.end(), back_inserter(res),
          bind1st(divides<long long>(), prod));
```

Comment: That's still an awesome looking code, though. With disclaimer that it uses division, I'd still upvote if given explanation.

Comment: Damn, I didn't read the question through. :s  @polygenelubricants explanation: the idea is to do it in two steps. First take the factorial of the first sequence of numbers. That's what the accumulate algorithm does (by default adds numbers, but can take any other binary operation to replace the addition, in this case a multiplication). Next I iterated over the input sequence a second time, transforming it such that the corresponding element in the output sequence the factorial I calculated in the previous step divided by the corresponding element in the input sequence.

Comment: "factorial of the first sequence"? wtf?  i meant the product of the sequence elements.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution in modern C++. It makes use of `std::transform` and is pretty easy to remember.

[Online code (wandbox).](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dwmiHI1mS2FWSHrt)

```cpp
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int>& multiply_up(vector<int>& v){
    v.insert(v.begin(),1);
    transform(v.begin()+1, v.end()
             ,v.begin()
             ,v.begin()+1
             ,[](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return b*a; }
             );
    v.pop_back();
    return v;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
    auto vr = v;

    reverse(vr.begin(),vr.end());
    multiply_up(v);
    multiply_up(vr);
    reverse(vr.begin(),vr.end());

    transform(v.begin(),v.end()
             ,vr.begin()
             ,v.begin()
             ,[](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return b*a; }
             );

    for(auto& i: v) cout << i << " "; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Precalculate the product of the numbers to the left and to the right of each element.
For every element the desired value is the product of it's neigbors's products.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned array[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5};

int main(void)
{
unsigned idx;

unsigned left[5]
        , right[5];
left[0] = 1;
right[4] = 1;

        /* calculate products of numbers to the left of [idx] */
for (idx=1; idx < 5; idx++) {
        left[idx] = left[idx-1] * array[idx-1];
        }

        /* calculate products of numbers to the right of [idx] */
for (idx=4; idx-- > 0; ) {
        right[idx] = right[idx+1] * array[idx+1];
        }

for (idx=0; idx <5 ; idx++) {
        printf("[%u] Product(%u*%u) = %u\n"
                , idx, left[idx] , right[idx]  , left[idx] * right[idx]  );
        }

return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
$ ./a.out
[0] Product(1*120) = 120
[1] Product(1*60) = 60
[2] Product(2*20) = 40
[3] Product(6*5) = 30
[4] Product(24*1) = 24
```

(UPDATE: now I look closer, this uses the same method as Michael Anderson, Daniel Migowski and polygenelubricants above)

Comment: What is the name of this algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Tricky:

Use the following:

```
public int[] calc(int[] params) {

int[] left = new int[n-1]
in[] right = new int[n-1]

int fac1 = 1;
int fac2 = 1;
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
    fac1 = fac1 * params[i];
    fac2 = fac2 * params[n-i];
    left[i] = fac1;
    right[i] = fac2; 
}
fac = 1;

int[] results = new int[n];
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
    results[i] = left[i] * right[i];
}
```

Yes, I am sure i missed some i-1 instead of i, but thats the way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

This is O(n^2) but f# is soooo beautiful:

```
List.fold (fun seed i -> List.mapi (fun j x -> if i=j+1 then x else x*i) seed) 
          [1;1;1;1;1]
          [1..5]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that either an enormous one liner or an O(n^2) solution to an O(n) problem are ever "beautiful".

Answer (score 1):

There also is a O(N^(3/2)) **non-optimal** solution. It is quite interesting, though.

First preprocess each partial multiplications of size N^0.5(this is done in O(N) time complexity). Then, calculation for each number's other-values'-multiple can be done in 2*O(N^0.5) time(why? because you only need to multiple the last elements of other ((N^0.5) - 1) numbers, and multiply the result with ((N^0.5) - 1) numbers that belong to the group of the current number). Doing this for each number, one can get O(N^(3/2)) time.

Example:

4 6 7 2 3 1 9 5 8

partial results: 
4*6*7 = 168
2*3*1 = 6
9*5*8 = 360

To calculate the value of 3, one needs to multiply the other groups' values 168*360, and then with 2*1.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution, Using division. with twice traversal.
Multiply all the elements and then start dividing it by each element.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] result = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            result[i] *= arr[j];

        }
        for (int k = arr.length - 1; k > i; k--) {
            result[i] *= arr[k];
        }
    }
    for (int i : result) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

This solution i came up with and i found it so clear what do you think!?

Comment: Your solution appears to have O(n^2) time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def productify(arr, prod, i):
    if i < len(arr):
        prod.append(arr[i - 1] * prod[i - 1]) if i > 0 else prod.append(1)
        retval = productify(arr, prod, i + 1)
        prod[i] *= retval
        return retval * arr[i]
    return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    prod = []
    productify(arr, prod, 0)
    print(prod)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Billz answer--sorry I can't comment, but here is a scala version that correctly handles duplicate items in the list, and is probably O(n):

```
val list1 = List(1, 7, 3, 3, 4, 4)
val view = list1.view.zipWithIndex map { x => list1.view.patch(x._2, Nil, 1).reduceLeft(_*_)}
view.force
```

returns:

```
List(1008, 144, 336, 336, 252, 252)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding my javascript solution here as I didn't find anyone suggesting this.
What is to divide, except to count the number of times you can extract a number from another number? I went through calculating the product of the whole array, and then iterate over each element, and substracting the current element until zero:

```
//No division operation allowed
// keep substracting divisor from dividend, until dividend is zero or less than divisor
function calculateProducsExceptCurrent_NoDivision(input){
  var res = [];
  var totalProduct = 1;
  //calculate the total product
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    totalProduct = totalProduct * input[i];
  }
  //populate the result array by "dividing" each value
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    var timesSubstracted = 0;
    var divisor = input[i];
    var dividend = totalProduct;
    while(divisor <= dividend){
      dividend = dividend - divisor;
      timesSubstracted++;
    }
    res.push(timesSubstracted);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just 2 passes up and down. Job done in O(N)

```
private static int[] multiply(int[] numbers) {
        int[] multiplied = new int[numbers.length];
        int total = 1;

        multiplied[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            multiplied[i] = numbers[i - 1] * multiplied[i - 1];
        }

        for (int j = numbers.length - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
            total *= numbers[j + 1];
            multiplied[j] = total * multiplied[j];
        }

        return multiplied;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,this solution can be considered that of C/C++.
Lets say we have an array "a" containing n elements
like a[n],then the pseudo code would be as below.

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  { 
    prod[j]=1;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
        if(i==j)
        continue;  
        else
        prod[j]=prod[j]*a[i];
  }
```

Comment: That takes O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 0):

```
{-
Recursive solution using sqrt(n) subsets. Runs in O(n).

Recursively computes the solution on sqrt(n) subsets of size sqrt(n). 
Then recurses on the product sum of each subset.
Then for each element in each subset, it computes the product with
the product sum of all other products.
Then flattens all subsets.

Recurrence on the run time is T(n) = sqrt(n)*T(sqrt(n)) + T(sqrt(n)) + n

Suppose that T(n) ≤ cn in O(n).

T(n) = sqrt(n)*T(sqrt(n)) + T(sqrt(n)) + n
    ≤ sqrt(n)*c*sqrt(n) + c*sqrt(n) + n
    ≤ c*n + c*sqrt(n) + n
    ≤ (2c+1)*n
    ∈ O(n)

Note that ceiling(sqrt(n)) can be computed using a binary search 
and O(logn) iterations, if the sqrt instruction is not permitted.
-}

otherProducts [] = []
otherProducts [x] = [1]
otherProducts [x,y] = [y,x]
otherProducts a = foldl' (++) [] $ zipWith (\s p -> map (*p) s) solvedSubsets subsetOtherProducts
    where 
      n = length a

      -- Subset size. Require that 1 < s < n.
      s = ceiling $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n

      solvedSubsets = map otherProducts subsets
      subsetOtherProducts = otherProducts $ map product subsets

      subsets = reverse $ loop a []
          where loop [] acc = acc
                loop a acc = loop (drop s a) ((take s a):acc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
int multiply(int a[],int n,int nextproduct,int i)
{
    int prevproduct=1;
    if(i>=n)
        return prevproduct;
    prevproduct=multiply(a,n,nextproduct*a[i],i+1);
    printf(" i=%d > %d\n",i,prevproduct*nextproduct);
    return prevproduct*a[i];
}

int main()
{
    int a[]={2,4,1,3,5};
    multiply(a,5,1,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly functional example, using C#:

```
            Func<long>[] backwards = new Func<long>[input.Length];
            Func<long>[] forwards = new Func<long>[input.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
            {
                var localIndex = i;
                backwards[i] = () => (localIndex > 0 ? backwards[localIndex - 1]() : 1) * input[localIndex];
                forwards[i] = () => (localIndex < input.Length - 1 ? forwards[localIndex + 1]() : 1) * input[localIndex];
            }

            var output = new long[input.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (0 == i)
                {
                    output[i] = forwards[i + 1]();
                }
                else if (input.Length - 1 == i)
                {
                    output[i] = backwards[i - 1]();
                }
                else
                {
                    output[i] = forwards[i + 1]() * backwards[i - 1]();
                }
            }
```

I'm not *entirely* certain that this is O(n), due to the semi-recursion of the created Funcs, but my tests seem to indicate that it's O(n) in time.

Answer (score 0):

To be complete here is the code in Scala:

```scala
val list1 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
for (elem <- list1) println(list1.filter(_ != elem) reduceLeft(_*_))
```

This will print out the following:

```
120
60
40
30
24
```

The program will filter out the current elem (_ != elem); and multiply the new list with reduceLeft method. I think this will be O(n) if you use scala view or Iterator for lazy eval.

Comment: Despite is very elegant, it doesn't work if there are more elements with the same value:

    val list1 = List(1, 7, 3, 3, 4, 4)

Comment: I tested the code again with repeating values.  It produces the following 1008
144
112
112
63
63  I think that it is correct for the given element.

Comment: That takes O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 0):

// This is the recursive solution in Java
// Called as following from main product(a,1,0);

```
public static double product(double[] a, double fwdprod, int index){
    double revprod = 1;
    if (index < a.length){
        revprod = product2(a, fwdprod*a[index], index+1);
        double cur = a[index];
        a[index] = fwdprod * revprod;
        revprod *= cur;
    }
    return revprod;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A neat solution with O(n) runtime:

1. For each element calculate the product of all the elements that occur before that and it store in an array "pre".
2. For each element calculate the product of all the elements that occur after that element and store it in an array "post"
3. Create a final array "result", for an element i,

   ```
   result[i] = pre[i-1]*post[i+1];
   ```

Comment: This is the same solution as the accepted one, right?

Answer (score 0):

We can exclude the `nums[j]` (where `j != i`) from list first, then get the product of the rest; The following is a `python way` to solve this puzzle:

```
from functools import reduce
def products(nums):
    return [ reduce(lambda x,y: x * y, nums[:i] + nums[i+1:]) for i in range(len(nums)) ]
print(products([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

[out]
[120, 60, 40, 30, 24]
```

Comment: That takes O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ptyhon version

```
  # This solution use O(n) time and O(n) space
  def productExceptSelf(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    N = len(nums)
    if N == 0: return

    # Initialzie list of 1, size N
    l_prods, r_prods = [1]*N, [1]*N

    for i in range(1, N):
      l_prods[i] = l_prods[i-1] * nums[i-1]

    for i in reversed(range(N-1)):
      r_prods[i] = r_prods[i+1] * nums[i+1]

    result = [x*y for x,y in zip(l_prods,r_prods)]
    return result

  # This solution use O(n) time and O(1) space
  def productExceptSelfSpaceOptimized(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    N = len(nums)
    if N == 0: return

    # Initialzie list of 1, size N
    result = [1]*N

    for i in range(1, N):
      result[i] = result[i-1] * nums[i-1]

    r_prod = 1
    for i in reversed(range(N)):
      result[i] *= r_prod
      r_prod *= nums[i]

    return result
```

Comment: Add some description to your answer. It would be more helpful than just piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use to C#:

```
    public int[] ProductExceptSelf(int[] nums)
    {
        int[] returnArray = new int[nums.Length];
        List<int> auxList = new List<int>();
        int multTotal = 0;

        // If no zeros are contained in the array you only have to calculate it once
        if(!nums.Contains(0))
        {
            multTotal = nums.ToList().Aggregate((a, b) => a * b);

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                returnArray[i] = multTotal / nums[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                auxList = nums.ToList();
                auxList.RemoveAt(i);
                if (!auxList.Contains(0))
                {
                    returnArray[i] = auxList.Aggregate((a, b) => a * b);
                }
                else
                {
                    returnArray[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }            

        return returnArray;
    }
```

Comment: That takes O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple Scala version in Linear O(n) time:

```
def getProductEff(in:Seq[Int]):Seq[Int] = {

   //create a list which has product of every element to the left of this element
   val fromLeft = in.foldLeft((1, Seq.empty[Int]))((ac, i) => (i * ac._1, ac._2 :+ ac._1))._2

   //create a list which has product of every element to the right of this element, which is the same as the previous step but in reverse
   val fromRight = in.reverse.foldLeft((1,Seq.empty[Int]))((ac,i) => (i * ac._1,ac._2 :+ ac._1))._2.reverse

   //merge the two list by product at index
   in.indices.map(i => fromLeft(i) * fromRight(i))

}
```

This works because essentially the answer is an array which has product of all elements to the left and to the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Pratik
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] array = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};      //  OUTPUT: 360  240  180  144  120
        int[] products = new int[array.length];
        arrayProduct(array, products);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(products));
    }

    public static void arrayProduct(int array[], int products[])
    {
        double sum = 0, EPSILON = 1e-9;

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            sum += Math.log(array[i]);

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            products[i] = (int) (EPSILON + Math.exp(sum - Math.log(array[i])));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[360, 240, 180, 144, 120]
```

> Time complexity : O(n)
>
> Space complexity: O(1)

Answer (score 0):

My first try, in Python. O(2n):

```
def product(l):
    product = 1
    num_zeroes = 0
    pos_zero = -1

    # Multiply all and set positions
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if x != 0:
            product *= x
            l[i] = 1.0/x
        else:
            num_zeroes += 1
            pos_zero = i

    # Warning! Zeroes ahead!
    if num_zeroes > 0:
        l = [0] * len(l)

        if num_zeroes == 1:
            l[pos_zero] = product

    else:
        # Now set the definitive elements
        for i in range(len(l)):
            l[i] = int(l[i] * product)

    return l


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("[0, 0, 4] = " + str(product([0, 0, 4])))
    print("[3, 0, 4] = " + str(product([3, 0, 4])))
    print("[1, 2, 3] = " + str(product([1, 2, 3])))
    print("[2, 3, 4, 5, 6] = " + str(product([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])))
    print("[2, 1, 2, 2, 3] = " + str(product([2, 1, 2, 2, 3])))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 4] = [0, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 4] = [0, 12, 0]
[1, 2, 3] = [6, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6] = [360, 240, 180, 144, 120]
[2, 1, 2, 2, 3] = [12, 24, 12, 12, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C implementation
O(n) time complexity.

INPUT

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter The Size of Array : ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    int array[x-1],i ;
    printf("Enter The Value of Array : \n");
      for( i = 0 ; i <= x-1 ; i++)
      {
          printf("Array[%d] = ",i);
          scanf("%d",&array[i]);
      }
    int left[x-1] , right[x-1];
    left[0] = 1 ;
    right[x-1] = 1 ;
      for( i = 1 ; i <= x-1 ; i++)
      {
          left[i] = left[i-1] * array[i-1];
      }
    printf("\nThis is Multiplication of array[i-1] and left[i-1]\n");
      for( i = 0 ; i <= x-1 ; i++)
      {
        printf("Array[%d] = %d , Left[%d] = %d\n",i,array[i],i,left[i]);
      }
      for( i = x-2 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
      {
          right[i] = right[i+1] * array[i+1];
      }
   printf("\nThis is Multiplication of array[i+1] and right[i+1]\n");
      for( i = 0 ; i <= x-1 ; i++)
      {
        printf("Array[%d] = %d , Right[%d] = %d\n",i,array[i],i,right[i]);
      }
    printf("\nThis is Multiplication of Right[i] * Left[i]\n");
      for( i = 0 ; i <= x-1 ; i++)
      {
          printf("Right[%d] * left[%d] = %d * %d = %d\n",i,i,right[i],left[i],right[i]*left[i]);
      }
    return 0 ;
}
```

---

OUTPUT

```
    Enter The Size of Array : 5
    Enter The Value of Array :
    Array[0] = 1
    Array[1] = 2
    Array[2] = 3
    Array[3] = 4
    Array[4] = 5

    This is Multiplication of array[i-1] and left[i-1]
    Array[0] = 1 , Left[0] = 1
    Array[1] = 2 , Left[1] = 1
    Array[2] = 3 , Left[2] = 2
    Array[3] = 4 , Left[3] = 6
    Array[4] = 5 , Left[4] = 24

    This is Multiplication of array[i+1] and right[i+1]
    Array[0] = 1 , Right[0] = 120
    Array[1] = 2 , Right[1] = 60
    Array[2] = 3 , Right[2] = 20
    Array[3] = 4 , Right[3] = 5
    Array[4] = 5 , Right[4] = 1

    This is Multiplication of Right[i] * Left[i]
    Right[0] * left[0] = 120 * 1 = 120
    Right[1] * left[1] = 60 * 1 = 60
    Right[2] * left[2] = 20 * 2 = 40
    Right[3] * left[3] = 5 * 6 = 30
    Right[4] * left[4] = 1 * 24 = 24

    Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 6.548 s
    Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def products(nums):
    prefix_products = []
    for num in nums:
        if prefix_products:
            prefix_products.append(prefix_products[-1] * num)
        else:
            prefix_products.append(num)

    suffix_products = []
    for num in reversed(nums):
        if suffix_products:
            suffix_products.append(suffix_products[-1] * num)
        else:
            suffix_products.append(num)
        suffix_products = list(reversed(suffix_products))

    result = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if i == 0:
            result.append(suffix_products[i + 1])
        elif i == len(nums) - 1:
            result.append(prefix_products[i-1])
        else:
            result.append(
                prefix_products[i-1] * suffix_products[i+1]
            )
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

We're factoring elements of the array, first from before the index i.e. the prefix then after the index or postfix

```
class Solution:

   def productExceptSelf(nums):

      length = len(nums)


      result = [1] * length


      prefix_product = 1


      postfix_product = 1

# we initialize the result and products


      for i in range(length)

      result[i] *= prefix_product


       prefix_product *= nums[i]

#we multiply the result by each number before the index

      for i in range(length-1,-1,-1)

      result[i] *= postfix_product


      postfix_product *= nums[i]

#same for after index
   return result
```

sorry on mobile on my walk

Answer (score 0):

php version
using array_product function without division.
If we set i value to 1 temporary, than array product will do exactly what we need

```
<?php
function product($key, $arr)
{
    $arr[$key] = 1;
    return array_product($arr);
};
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$newarr = array();


foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

    $newarr[$key] = product($key, $arr);
}
print_r($newarr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this!

```
import java.util.*;
class arrProduct
{
 public static void main(String args[])
     {
         //getting the size of the array
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            int noe = s.nextInt();

        int out[]=new int[noe];
         int arr[] = new int[noe];

         // getting the input array
         for(int k=0;k<noe;k++)
         {
             arr[k]=s.nextInt();
         }

         int val1 = 1,val2=1;
         for(int i=0;i<noe;i++)
         {
             int res=1;

                 for(int j=1;j<noe;j++)
                 {
                if((i+j)>(noe-1))
                {

                    int diff = (i+j)-(noe);

                    if(arr[diff]!=0)
                    {
                    res = res * arr[diff];
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    if(arr[i+j]!=0)
                    {
                    res= res*arr[i+j];
                    }
                }


             out[i]=res;

         }
         }

         //printing result
         System.out.print("Array of Product: [");
         for(int l=0;l<out.length;l++)
         {
             if(l!=out.length-1)
             {
            System.out.print(out[l]+",");
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.print(out[l]);
             }
         }
         System.out.print("]");
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question!  Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Coded up using EcmaScript 2015

```
'use strict'

/*
Write a function that, given an array of n integers, returns an array of all possible products using exactly (n - 1) of those integers.
*/
/*
Correct behavior:
- the output array will have the same length as the input array, ie. one result array for each skipped element
- to compare result arrays properly, the arrays need to be sorted
- if array lemgth is zero, result is empty array
- if array length is 1, result is a single-element array of 1

input array: [1, 2, 3]
1*2 = 2
1*3 = 3
2*3 = 6
result: [2, 3, 6]
*/
class Test {
  setInput(i) {
    this.input = i
    return this
  }
  setExpected(e) {
    this.expected = e.sort()
    return this
  }
}

class FunctionTester {
  constructor() {
    this.tests = [
      new Test().setInput([1, 2, 3]).setExpected([6, 3, 2]),
      new Test().setInput([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).setExpected([3 * 4 * 5 * 6, 2 * 4 * 5 * 6, 2 * 3 * 5 * 6, 2 * 3 * 4 * 6, 2 * 3 * 4 * 5]),
    ]
  }

  test(f) {
    console.log('function:', f.name)
    this.tests.forEach((test, index) => {
      var heading = 'Test #' + index + ':'
      var actual = f(test.input)
      var failure = this._check(actual, test)

      if (!failure) console.log(heading, 'input:', test.input, 'output:', actual)
      else console.error(heading, failure)

      return !failure
    })
  }

  testChain(f) {
    this.test(f)
    return this
  }

  _check(actual, test) {
      if (!Array.isArray(actual)) return 'BAD: actual not array'
      if (actual.length !== test.expected.length) return 'BAD: actual length is ' + actual.length + ' expected: ' + test.expected.length
      if (!actual.every(this._isNumber)) return 'BAD: some actual values are not of type number'
      if (!actual.sort().every(isSame)) return 'BAD: arrays not the same: [' + actual.join(', ') + '] and [' + test.expected.join(', ') + ']'

      function isSame(value, index) {
        return value === test.expected[index]
      }
  }

  _isNumber(v) {
    return typeof v === 'number'
  }
}

/*
Efficient: use two iterations of an aggregate product
We need two iterations, because one aggregate goes from last-to-first
The first iteration populates the array with products of indices higher than the skipped index
The second iteration calculates products of indices lower than the skipped index and multiplies the two aggregates

input array:
1 2 3
   2*3
1*    3
1*2

input array:
2 3 4 5 6
    (3 * 4 * 5 * 6)
(2) *     4 * 5 * 6
(2 * 3) *     5 * 6
(2 * 3 * 4) *     (6)
(2 * 3 * 4 * 5)

big O: (n - 2) + (n - 2)+ (n - 2) = 3n - 6 => o(3n)
*/
function multiplier2(ns) {
  var result = []

  if (ns.length > 1) {
    var lastIndex = ns.length - 1
    var aggregate

    // for the first iteration, there is nothing to do for the last element
    var index = lastIndex
    for (var i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
      if (!i) aggregate = ns[index]
      else aggregate *= ns[index]
      result[--index] = aggregate
    }

    // for second iteration, there is nothing to do for element 0
    // aggregate does not require multiplication for element 1
    // no multiplication is required for the last element
    for (var i = 1; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
      if (i === 1) aggregate = ns[0]
      else aggregate *= ns[i - 1]
      if (i !== lastIndex) result[i] *= aggregate
      else result[i] = aggregate
    }
  } else if (ns.length === 1) result[0] = 1

  return result
}

/*
Create the list of products by iterating over the input array

the for loop is iterated once for each input element: that is n
for every n, we make (n - 1) multiplications, that becomes n (n-1)
O(n^2)
*/
function multiplier(ns) {
  var result = []

  for (var i = 0; i < ns.length; i++) {
    result.push(ns.reduce((reduce, value, index) =>
      !i && index === 1 ? value // edge case: we should skip element 0 and it's the first invocation: ignore reduce
      : index !== i ? reduce * value // multiply if it is not the element that should be skipped
      : reduce))
  }

  return result
}

/*
Multiply by clone the array and remove one of the integers

O(n^2) and expensive array manipulation
*/
function multiplier0(ns) {
  var result = []

  for (var i = 0; i < ns.length; i++) {
    var ns1 = ns.slice() // clone ns array
    ns1.splice(i, 1) // remove element i
    result.push(ns1.reduce((reduce, value) => reduce * value))
  }

  return result
}

new FunctionTester().testChain(multiplier0).testChain(multiplier).testChain(multiplier2)
```

run with Node.js v4.4.5 like:

> node --harmony integerarrays.js

```
function: multiplier0
Test #0: input: [ 1, 2, 3 ] output: [ 2, 3, 6 ]
Test #1: input: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] output: [ 120, 144, 180, 240, 360 ]
function: multiplier
Test #0: input: [ 1, 2, 3 ] output: [ 2, 3, 6 ]
Test #1: input: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] output: [ 120, 144, 180, 240, 360 ]
function: multiplier2
Test #0: input: [ 1, 2, 3 ] output: [ 2, 3, 6 ]
Test #1: input: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] output: [ 120, 144, 180, 240, 360 ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another simple concept which solves the problem in `O(N)`.

```
        int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] outArray = new int[arr.length]; 
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            int res=Arrays.stream(arr).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
            outArray[i] = res/arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outArray));
```

Comment: OP specifically states no division, re: `res/arr[i]`

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution with `O(n)` space and `O(n^2)` time complexity provided below,

```
public static int[] findEachElementAsProduct1(final int[] arr) {

        int len = arr.length;

//        int[] product = new int[len];
//        Arrays.fill(product, 1);

        int[] product = IntStream.generate(() -> 1).limit(len).toArray();


        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {

                if (i == j) {
                    continue;
                }

                product[i] *= arr[j];
            }
        }

        return product;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I got asked this question recently, and whilst I couldn't get O(N) during it, I had a different approach (unfortunately O(N^2)) but thought I'd share anyway.

Convert to `List<Integer>` first.

Loop through original array `array.length()` times.

Use a `while` loop to multiple the next set of required numbers:

```
while (temp < list.size() - 1) {
    res *= list.get(temp);
    temp++;
}
```

Then add `res` to a new array (which of course you've declared earlier), then add the value at `array[i]` to the `List`, and continue so forth.

I know this won't be of great use, but it's what I came up with under the pressures of an interview :)

```
    int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    int[] newarray = new int[array.length];
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int temp = i;
        while (temp < list.size() - 1) {
            res *= list.get(temp);
            temp++;
        }
        newarray[i] = res;
        list.add(array[i]);
        res = 1;
    }
```

> Output: [24, 120, 60, 40, 30]

Answer (score -1):

Here's a one-liner solution in Ruby.

`nums.map { |n| (num - [n]).inject(:*) }`

Comment: That takes O(n^2) time.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my concise solution using python.

```
from functools import reduce

def excludeProductList(nums_):
    after = [reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, nums_[i:]) for i in range(1, len(nums_))] + [1]
    before = [1] + [reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, nums_[:i]) for i in range(1, len(nums_))]
    zippedList =  list(zip(before, after))
    finalList = list(map(lambda x: x[0]*x[1], zippedList))
    return finalList
```

Comment: That takes O(n^2) time.

Comment: @Sneftel, thanks for your comment but could you also point out which line is O(n^2)?
after and before I believe are O(n) when using itertools' reduce;
finalList is a mapping on a list so I would assume this is also O(n);
Thanks in advance

Comment: `reduce` is O(n) and you’re doing it n times.

Comment: (What you want is `itertools.accumulate`, not a list comprehension.)

Answer (score -1):

ruby solution

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
result = []
a.each {|x| result.push( (a-[x]).reject(&:zero?).reduce(:*)) }
puts result
```

Comment: That takes O(n^2) time.

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] b = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };            
int j;
for(int i=0;i<b.Length;i++)
{
  int prod = 1;
  int s = b[i];
  for(j=i;j<b.Length-1;j++)
  {
    prod = prod * b[j + 1];
  }
int pos = i;    
while(pos!=-1)
{
  pos--;
  if(pos!=-1)
     prod = prod * b[pos];                    
}
Console.WriteLine("\n Output is {0}",prod);
}
```

Comment: Try to add little description with code for others to understand the solution.

Comment: That takes O(n^2) time.

Answer (score -1):

A variation in JavaScript using `reduce`

```js
const getProduct = arr => arr.reduce((acc, value) => acc * value);

const arrayWithExclusion = (arr, node) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, val, j) => (node !== j ? [...acc, val] : acc), []);

const getProductWithExclusion = arr => {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    result.push(getProduct(arrayWithExclusion(arr, i)));
  }

  return result;
};
```

Comment: That takes O(n^2) time.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with 2 solutions in Javascript, one with division and one without

```js
// without division
function methodOne(arr) {
  return arr.map(item => {
    return arr.reduce((result, num) => {
      if (num !== item) {
        result = result * num;
      }
      return result;
    },1)
  });
}

// with division
function methodTwo(arr) {
  var mul = arr.reduce((result, num) => {
    result = result * num;
    return result;
  },1)
 return arr.map(item => mul/item);
}

console.log(methodOne([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(methodTwo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: Your methodOne is not O(n).

Answer (score -2):

```
    int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] product = new int[arr1.Length];              

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < product.Length; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
                product[j] = product[j] == 0 ? arr1[i] : product[j] * arr1[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok, was not sure of O(N) part, soes that mean using just a single loop ? thanks

Comment: you can use multiple loops, but not NESTED loops.

Comment: @isthatcode see this link:  http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/