# How to get it working in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interview Q: given an array of numbers, return array of products of all other numbers (no division)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680548/interview-q-given-an-array-of-numbers-return-array-of-products-of-all-other-num)

I came across an interview task/question that really got me thinking ... so here it goes:

You have an array A[N] of N numbers. You have to compose an array Output[N] such that Output[i] will be equal to multiplication of all the elements of A[N] except A[i]. For example Output[0] will be multiplication of A[1] to A[N-1] and Output[1] will be multiplication of A[0] and from A[2] to A[N-1]. Solve it without division operator and in O(n).

I really tried to come up with a solution but I always end up with a complexity of O(n^2). Perhaps the is anyone smarter than me who can tell me an algorithm that works in O(n) or at least give me a hint...

Comment: I would refuse to answer this kind of interview questions, frankly. It was just ok until I read "without division operator".

Comment: @daniel: they didn't exclude `pow(n, -1)` and that question so richly deserves an answer using it...

Comment: @KennyTM, isn't it a company with a job ad on Stack Overflow which uses this interview question? :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Construct two temporary arrays - B[N] and C[N]. Form each element of B[N] as the product of the A[N] elements to its left (including itself) - working left to right, N operations. Form each element of C[N] as the product of the A[N] elements to its right (including itself) - working right to left, N operations.

Then A[n] = B[n-1] * C[n+1] - another N operations to work this out. You end up with just short of 3N operations, which is O(N). It's just short, because B[0] and C[N-1], and the first and last A, don't require multiplication. Also, C[0] = B[N-1], so I think you should need exactly 3N-5 operations.

Comment: What is the logic behind this idea? I implemented it and it works fine , but any logic behind?

Comment: Barry, take sequence "1 2 3 4" for example, draw matrix 4x4 and fill those values in each row with center diagonal leaving empty. You will see logic behind this idea.

Answer (score 0):

You generate two intermediate arrays, `L`, where `L[i] = products of A[0]..A[i-1]`, and `U` where `U[i] = products of A[i+1]..A[N-1]`. These can both be generated in O(n). Your output value `B[i]` will just be `L[i] * U[i]` - again this is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Cheating I know but:-

```
for (x = 0 ; x < n ; x++) {
   bigtot = bigtot * in[x];
}
for (x = 0 ; x < n ; x++) {
      out[n] = bigot;
      for ( y = in[x]; y > 0 ; y--) {
         out[n] = out[n] - in[x]
      } 
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like O(N) to me ?

Comment: Not realy the second loop is dependent on the individual value of a particular table entry -- so its bad for each entry, but adding another entry just affects the new entry so it is O(N) even though each n is pretty awful