# Interview question on problem solving (arrays)

Tags: algorithm

There is an array of integers, lets say 3,5,7,9. You are supposed to create another array and populate it such that the second array's 0th position should be a product of all numbers from the first array excluding the number at its 0th position, meaning it should be 5x7x9(excluding 3), number at the index 1 of the second array will be product of 3x7x9 (excluding 5).

The first answer that came up to my mind was having 2 for loops which will lead to a time complexity of O(n2). Later I figured this:

Multiplying all the numbers in the first array(3x5x7x9), and while populating the second array I will divide this product by the number at that position. divide by 3 if I am populating the 0th position, divide by 5 if I am populating the 1st position and so on. This would bring down the complexity from O(n2) to probably O(2n).

But the interviewer says division is not allowed. I could not think of anything else but storing the different possible multiples in some kind of a data structure and using it while populating. I gave up, but when asked for the answer he said he would maintain 2 arrays of forward and backward multiples. When asked about the space complexity issue of the solution, he said it could be optimized.

Comment: One little technical quibble: O(2n) is exactly O(n).

Comment: Maybe he meant that in a sense it's optimal, since the problem has a space complexity of `O(n)` and the solution adds another `O(n)` which remains `O(n)` in total.

Comment: I am not good at analysis. I meant O(2n) because there is one for loop to get the product of all the elements in the first array and another for loop to populate the second array.

Comment: @Charlie knows what you meant...  He is saying that O(2n) is the same as O(3n) is the same as O(1000000n) is the same as O(n).

Comment: Is the question about the interviewer's space optimisation or the way his solution works? His solution is rather simple...

Comment: He just wanted an answer to the problem but was not happy with my solution. He only mentioned about his solution when I asked him how he would solve the problem. And I was wondering how his is better than what I suggested, because coming up with his array of forward and backward multiples would only add to thee time and space complexity.

Comment: @Chris, see my answer, his is `O(n)` in both time and space, and his doesn't use division (which in my opinion is a silly way of him saying "I have a particular solution in mind, and am not open to you finding alternatives")

Comment: I think I can shed some light on this: the interviewer didn't think of your simpler, more elegant solution, so division was not allowed. Do they also disallow division in their code, and everybody has to code around that arbitrary restriction?

Comment: @omrib: But on a more pragmatic point of view, isn't division typically slower?

Comment: @omrib I know it was a contrived restriction. I didn't mind that but what disappointed me was he did not ask me any further problem solving questions after this. This was the sole question. Yeah, I could not come up with what he had in his mind but I think he should have atleast given me another opportunity by asking another question.

Comment: @Ziyao Yup I agree division is definitely slower.

Comment: This actually was discussed several times here, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2680548/775806 and links from there.

Comment: @Ziyao: Division is slower than multiplication, but Chris gave a solution that requires O(1) more memory (the result can be stored in place in the array), whereas the interviewer's solution requires O(n) more memory. Is speed more important that memory? The interviewer should have explained all the restrictions at the beginning and not just pull them out of his sleeve.

Comment: This is a duplicate question : see the most voted solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680548/interview-q-given-an-array-of-numbers-return-array-of-products-of-all-other-num/2680697#2680697

Comment: This is a duplicate question : see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680548/interview-q-given-an-array-of-numbers-return-array-of-products-of-all-other-num/2680697#2680697

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if the question is about the space or about the solution itself. Since everyone has been providing solutions it leads me to think they didn't understand the interviewer's solution, so here is an explanation:

We maintain two arrays. The first, the running product of the numbers of the original array. So the element at place `i` will be the product of the first `i` elements in the original array (no latex, but the `i`<sup>th</sup> entry has value it's `pi{j=0 to i} j`). And the second array is simply the reverse direction of that, so the `i`<sup>th</sup> entry will have value: `pi{j=N-i to N} j`.

To construct the final array required, we simply run along each of our two arrays and multiply entries. So the `i`<sup>th</sup> value in the final array, will be the product of all the entries, which is the product of `0` to `i-1` times the product of `i+1` to `N`, which is the product of the first array's `i-1` entry and the second array's `i+1` entry.

Total time and space `O(n)`

Comment: this is what I understood by reading your solution: if the input array has 3,5,7,9. The **firstarray** will have 3, 15(3x5), 105(3x5x7), 945(3x5x7x9) and the **secondarray** will have 945(3x5x7x9), 315(5x7x9), 63(7x9), 9. And then you get the **finalarray** where finalarray[i] = firstarray[i] * secondarray[i]? If that is the case then it does not solve the problem. I hope I am wrong in understanding your solution.

Comment: @ChrisOdney: Will finalarray[i] = firstarray[i-1] * secondarray[i+1] (as in davin's answer and my answer) be fine? If not, please elaborate:)

Comment: @Chris, that's correct as far as the big picture goes, but be precise with your indexes. I said `i-1` and `i+1`, not `i` and `i`, but I didn't double check either. Let's use your example: **original-array** =[3,5,7,9] **first-array** =[3,15,105,945] **second-array** =[945,315,63,9] so **final-array** =[1*315,3*63,15*9,945*1] (I assume out-of-bounds index values are 1). That will be the correct solution.

Comment: Got that, thanks. When it comes to complexity, AFAI Understand it is O(n) like my solution but the only difference is it does not use division?

Comment: But the space complexity is higher. It uses 2 extra array of size n.

Comment: @Chris, which is still `O(n)`. This solution has higher constants (for both time and space complexity), but the same complexity.

Comment: @Chris: You can get away without constructing the "backwards" array of products.  See the last update to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Store the elements 1 to i's product into an array `A`, with `A[i]`
>      being the product of element 1 to element i;
> 2. Store the elements i to n (size of input)'s product into an array
>      `B`, with `B[i]` being the product of element i to element n;
> 3. When result[i] is needed, use A[i-1]*B[i+1]. Corner cases are
>      trivial this way, just use B[1] and A[n-2] (with A[n-1] being the last
>      element).

Comment: Thanks. Excuse my naivete I could not follow it the first time I read it.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can do it in O(n log n).

Store the product of the first half of the numbers and second half of the numbers.

Also store the product of the first quarter, second quarter, third quarter, and fourth quarter.

Also store the product of the first eighth, second eighth, ... 8th eighth.

And so on.

You can build this from the ground up by computing the product of each pair, then the product of each of *those* pairs, and so on.

Total amount of extra data here is O(n) and takes O(n) to compute (easy to show).

Now, to compute the output for (say) element 0, you take the product of the second half, the product of the second quarter (i.e., the second half of the first quarter), the product of the second half of the first eighth, etc., and multiply them together.  There are log n such numbers, so this operation is log n.

To compute the product for element k, write k in binary and flip its bits.  The high bit then tells you which half to start with; the next bit tells you which half of the remaining half to use next; the next bit tells you which half of the remaining quarter to use next; and so on.

So any output element can be calculated in log n time.  Do that for each of the n output elements and you get O(n log n).

[edit]

Of course, the "forward and backward multiples" approach works, too.  Guess I should read the question more carefully.  :-)

[edit 2]

As for the interviewer's (and davin's) solution, you do not actually need to construct an extra array...  Assuming you can edit the values in the output array.

First, construct the output array B such that B[i] = A[0]*A[1]*...*A[i-1] and B[0]=1.  You can do this incrementally, so this is linear time:

```
B[0] = 1;
for (i=1 ; i < n ; ++i) {
    B[i] = B[i-1] * A[i];
}
```

Next, scan *backwards* from n-2 to compute the answers, keeping track of the "product so far":

```
x = A[n-1];
for (j=n-2 ; j >= 0 ; ++j) {
    B[j] *= x;
    x *= A[j];
}
```

This solves the problem in O(n) without building an extra array.

Comment: When you say nlogn have you also considered the complexity involved in coming up with the halfs, quarters, eights?

Comment: @ChrisOdney: you only need n/2+n/4+n/8+...=n-1 operations for that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what he meant is that, given an array A={a_1, ..., a_n} he would create two new arrays:

F_A={a_1, a_1 * a_2, ..., a_1 * ... * a_n}

which can be constructed in linear time by maintaining a cumulative product while iterating forward over the array, and

B_A={a_1 * ... * a_n, ..., a_n * a_(n-1), a_n}

which can be constructed in linear time by maintaining a cumulative product while iterating in the reverse direction over the array.

Now, to populate index i in the result array you simply multiply F_A[i-1] with B_A[i+1]:

F_A[i-1] * B_A[i+1] = [a_1 * ... * a_(i-1)] * [a_(i+1) * ... * a_n]

Comment: You can actually store one of the cumulative arrays in place of the original array.

Answer (score 1):

What about absuing Logarithm. Instead of dividing you subtract?

But if you can modify 1st array you could do somthing like

```
//pop arr2
r=1
for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
{
   r=r*arr1[i]
   arr2[i]=r
}

//modify arr1
r=1
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
   r=r*arr1[i]
   arr1[i]=r
}

//fix arr2
arr2[0]=arr2[1];
for(i=1;i<len-1;i--)
{
     arr2[i]=arr2[i+1]*arr1[i-1];
}
arr2[len-1]=arr1[len-2];
```