# For which cases does this algorithm fail?

Tags: c++, algorithm, testing

What does it do - element at index 'i' is the product of all input elements except for the input element at 'i'.

As an example, if arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, then

output = { 2*3*4, 1*3*4, 1*2*4, 1*2*3 }.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    long long int arr[1000]={0},prod=1;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
        prod*=arr[i];
    }
    if(prod!=0)
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cout<<(prod/arr[i])<<endl;
        }
    else
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cout<<"0"<<endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you KNOW it fails or are you asking people for a code review?

Comment: It FAILS. I am not able to figure out for which case though

Comment: How do you know that it fails?

Comment: Running it on an Online Judge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest case for which it fails is  `2 0 1`. The correct result would be `1 0`, your result is `0 0`.

More generally, it fails if there is exactly one zero and at least one non-zero in the input set.

Comment: How would the output in this case be `1 0` ? {0*1,2*1,2*0} should be the output right?

Comment: The first digit is the count (see `cin>>n`). The data set is `0 1`, the size is `2`.

Answer (score 0):

As was already noted, the problem is when one of the inputs is zero, and you try to divide by zero. To properly compute the products, an algorithm which only performs multiplications and no divisions is needed, such as the following one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

// Input: an array of 2^(exp) doubles
// Output: an array of 2^(exp) doubles, where each one is the
//         product of all the numbers at different indices in
//         the input
// Return value: the product of all inputs
double products (unsigned int exp, const double *in, double *out)
{
    if (exp == 0) {
        out[0] = 1;
        return in[0];
    }

    size_t half_n = (size_t)1 << (exp - 1);

    double prod_left = products(exp - 1, in, out);
    double prod_right = products(exp - 1, in + half_n, out + half_n);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < half_n; i++) {
        out[i] *= prod_right;
        out[half_n + i] *= prod_left;
    }

    return prod_left * prod_right;
}

int main ()
{
    double in[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    double out[8];
    products(3, in, out);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%f ", out[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This requires O(n*log(n)) time and no extra space, except for the O(log(n)) space used by the recursion. While it's nice and easy to understand, it is not optimal; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680548/interview-q-given-an-array-of-numbers-return-array-of-products-of-all-other-nu).