# Efficiently multiply (n-1) elements of an array

Tags: c++, c, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interview Q: given an array of numbers, return array of products of all other numbers (no division)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680548/interview-q-given-an-array-of-numbers-return-array-of-products-of-all-other-nu)

I have two arrays `inputArray` and `resultArray` having `n` elements each.
The task is that the nth element in `resultArray` should have the multiplication of all elements in `inputArray` except the nth element of `inputArray` (`n-1` elements in all).
eg. `inputArray={1,2,3,4}`
then `resultArray={24,12,8,6}`
This is easy...

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    if(i != j) resultArray[i] *= inputArray[j];
```

But the problem is that the complexity shouldn't exceed ***O(n)***
Also we are not allowed to use division.
How do I solve this?

Comment: Would it count as cheating to sum `log10 (inputArray[i])`, then do `resultArray[i] = pow(10., sum - log10(inputArray[i]))`?

Comment: This is very simple if you can convert this problem to a division. What is the i'th element in the result if it is seen as the result of a division rather than multiplication?

Answer (score 4):

Without spoiling too much, you should try and use two variables to store the result of the multiplications: both the cumulative result of the multiplications on the left of the i'th element and on the right of the i'th element.

Comment: Aw you told him the standard way.. why not let him do it the cool way?

Comment: this way is much faster than trying to find multiplicative inverses modulo 2^32 (even if it has the same overall algorithmic complexity)

Comment: @ronalchn but it's not cool, and the only requirement was that is should be O(n), not as fast as possible

Comment: in a programming contest, you want the solution that you can code as fast as possible, both programming time as well as run-time is valuable

Comment: @ronalchn that's not what the question says. And besides, finding the multiplicative inverse is not that slow. Just a handful of multiplications.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a DP approach, something like this:

```
vector<int> products(const vector<int>& input) {
    int N = input.size();
    vector<int> partial(N+1); // partial[i] = input[0]...input[i-1]. partial[0] = 1
    partial[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) partial[i+1] = input[i]*partial[i];
    vector<int> ans(N);
    int current = 1;
    for (int i = N-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        // current is equal to input[i+1]...input[N-1]
        ans[i] = partial[i]*current;
        current *= input[i];
    }
    return ans;
}
```

One possible usage for this approach is when you are working with things you cannot divide by (think of this same problem with matrices, for instance).

I did this solution using STL vector, but of course the code can be easily "translated" to work with C arrays.

Comment: I just realized that this is actually similar to Ben Rujil, without divisions. Nice.

Comment: By DP what is intended is two-pass (i.e., Dual Pass, DP). The important part of the homework being that O(N) doesn't necessarily have to mean single-pass; any fixed-number of passes (2 in this case) qualify as O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that multiplication by an odd number is reversible - by using only multiplications? See Hacker's Delight, called something like "exact division". This trick can be extended to even numbers as well, as explained there. So you can "divide" the nth number out with a couple of multiplications - and since this is homework, I'll leave it up to you to find out how.

Answer (score 1):

```
main()
{

      int i,l,r,x[5]={1,2,3,4,5},y[5]; // x is the initial array, y is the final array

      int n = 5; // n be the size of the array, here already defined as 5

      l = 1; // l is the product of the values of the left side of an index in x
      r = 1; // r is the product of the values of the right side of an index in x

      for (i=0 ; i<5 ; i++) y[i]=1; // initialising all y values to 1

      for (i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
      {
          y[i] = y[i]*l ;
          y[n-i-1] = y[n-i-1]*r;

          l = l*x[i];
          r = r*x[n-i-1];

      }

      for (i=0; i<5; i++) printf("%d\n",y[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing Daniel Fleischman's answer, I decided I had to give my own implementation, since his has so many lines of code!

```
int i, buffer=1, result[n];
for(result[0]=1,i=1;i<n;i++) result[i] = result[i-1]*inputArray[i-1];
for(i=n-1,buffer=1;i>=0;buffer*=inputArray[i],i--) result[i]*=buffer;
```

Three lines of code (with all the fat cut out).

http://ideone.com/EaQiu

Comment: I didn't know the OP was doing homework for ioccc..

Comment: it's not about LOC but about readability

Comment: readability relies more on good naming and documentation of functions, rather than making simple functions take many lines of code.

Comment: It's tagged as homework, so actually code isn't really welcome.