# Implement Number division by multiplication method

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, division

Given an integer array `a[N]`, some of which are zeros. Return an new integer array `b[N]`, while `value = a[0] * a[1] * ... * a[N-1]`, and `b[i] = value/a[i]`.

One way to return `b[N]` is firstly calculate `value`, and then `b[i]` equals to value divided by `a[i]`. The time complexity is `O(N)`. This is not good enough since it may generate run-time error.

I want a way of implementing it without division, `only by multiplication`. Also at the same time the time complexity should be `O(N)`.

Can anyone think of a way to implement it? Any language is OK. Or you can help me with pseudo-code.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680548/given-an-array-of-numbers-return-array-of-products-of-all-other-numbers-no-div

Comment: b[i] = c[i] * d[i]. c[i] = a[0]*a[1]*...*a[i-1]; d[i] = a[i+1]*a[i+2]...a[n-1]. c[i] = c[i-1]*a[i-1], c[0] = 1; d[i] = d[i+1]*a[i+1], d[n-1] = 1. This is the key of the method.