# Interview Q- product of all elements in array without the current element

Tags: arrays

I recently came across an interview [question](http://thereq.com/q/147/java-software-interview-question/products-and-arrays) and was wondering what could be the solution. Any ideas to solve it are greatly appreciated.

Given an array A[N] containing N numbers. Create an array Output[N] where Output[i] is equal to the product of all the elements of A[N] except A[i].

For example Output[0] is the product of A[1](http://thereq.com/q/147/java-software-interview-question/products-and-arrays) to A[N-1] and Output[1](http://thereq.com/q/147/java-software-interview-question/products-and-arrays) is the product of A[0] and from A[2] to A[N-1].

**Do this without using the division operator. Do it in O(n).**

Comment: Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic on which questions are on-topic - at least, you should have tried something yourself

Comment: Andreas: Thanks for your feedback. The question was posted as I couldn't find a solution without using division operator and time complexity as O(n). Appreciate if you could provide inputs rather than criticizing the intent.

Comment: My intention was not to criticize you, but to try helping you to post a better question, so that you get better answers. Sorry if this was misleading.

Comment: Similar question has been answered; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680548/given-an-array-of-numbers-return-array-of-products-of-all-other-numbers-no-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip: do two iterations over the array - on the first one put in each cell the product of all preceding elements and on the second one multiply this by the product of all succeding elements.

Comment: Wow I way overthought this... First pass compute the product. Pick a prime N bigger than that. Multiply product by the modular multiplicative inverse over N.  prod/x == prod * x^-1 == prod * x^(N-2) mod N

Comment: Actually, that would let me solve it in 1 pass, if I knew the range or product beforehand.