# Find product of array elements

Tags: java, algorithm

Today, in the job interview i was asked a question:
we have an array

```
[3,1,2,4]
```

write the function thatfind composition of elements not including one element during itearion and return new array,it's mean that

```
for 3 composition will be : 1*2*4 = 8

for 1 : 3*2*4=24

for 2 : 3*1*4 = 12

for 4: 3*1*2 = 6
```

So answer will be `8,24,12,6`
It's pretty easy but i have 2 constraint

1) You can't use operator "/"

2) Your algorithm must be `O(n)`

That i didn't write an answer. How this task should be done?

Comment: Interesting question, but maybe better suited for [cs.se].

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Not sure I agree.

Comment: Would be fine here if OP actually made an attempt and explained what was wrong with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given an array of numbers, return array of products of all other numbers (no division)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680548/given-an-array-of-numbers-return-array-of-products-of-all-other-numbers-no-div)

Comment: How would you solve finding the product of _all_ the numbers in the array?  If you can do that,you just need to add the additional step of excluding a specific number from the product.

Comment: Just compute product of all elements and then multiply it by `Math.pow(elementToExclude, -1)` - no division operator.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Yeah, I'm not 100% sure either. Since there's no code, I figure it's off topic here and at [codereview.se]. Since op is asking for an algorithm and the first bullet point on the cs help page says questions about _algorithms, models of computation_ are ok, that seemed like a logical place.

Answer (score 2):

This solution iterates twice over the array. Once for multiplication and then for division, avoiding the "/" character by using the power operation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {3, 1, 2, 4};
    int m = Arrays.stream(a).reduce(1, (left, right) -> left * right);
    IntStream.range(0, a.length).forEach(i -> {
        System.out.printf("%s : %02d%n", m, + (int) (m * Math.pow(a[i], -1.0)));
    });
}
```

This prints:

```
24 : 08
24 : 24
24 : 12
24 : 06
```

Comment: Are you sure this is O(n)?

Comment: Well it is O(2n). It calculates the multiplication and then iterates again and divides avoiding the "/" operator. But typically the "2" should be irrelevant in this case.

Comment: I really doubt that the interviewer was testing whether or not he know how to avoid the "/" using the power operation.

Comment: Well, then the interviewer should have stated it :) . It would be his lack of explicitness, not a lack of diligence by the interviewee who presents such a solution.

Comment: nicely answered. If only interviewers were this open-minded :p