# still working on this question and have no idea what this explanation even means

Tags: algorithm

```
Given an array nums of n integers where n > 1,  return an array output such that output[i] is equal to the product of all the elements of nums except nums[i].

Example:

Input:  [1,2,3,4]
Output: [24,12,8,6]
Constraint: It's guaranteed that the product of the elements of any prefix or suffix of the array (including the whole array) fits in a 32 bit integer.

Note: Please solve it without division and in O(n).

Follow up:
Could you solve it with constant space complexity? (The output array does not count as extra space for the purpose of space complexity analysis.)
```

(source: [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/product-of-array-except-self/))

This is the question I've been working on. I had to look up a solution in the end and this line is to me not very straight-forward. Could anyone please elaborate more on it so that I could get the hang of it.

the explanation is:

**1. we can make use of the product of all the numbers to the left and all the numbers to the right of the index.***

**2. Multiplying these two individual products would give us the desired result as well**

How come left to right and right to left can give desired results;;

Answer (score 1):

I will give an explanation that doesn't involve code and just elaborate on the explanation of the solution, and I'll make use of the example provided above.

Okay, so we will have this input `Input:  [1,2,3,4]` and we need to return an array with the same number of elements, and each element value's should be the result of multiplying the rest of the elements, so for the first position the expected result is: `2 * 3 * 4`, for the second element it should be `1 * 3 * 4`, third element should be: `1 * 2 * 4` and finally for the fourth element it should be  `1 * 2 * 3`. Now, if we wanted to obtain the value for any of our output indexes, say, `index 1` what elements are there to the `left` of our index? just `1`, and what are those elements to the `right`? `3 and 4`, ok let's take the result of multiplying ALL of the elements to the left. we have `1` and let's do the same for ALL of the elements to the right `3 * 4 = 12` what happens when we multiply both of our results? We obtain `1 * 12 = 12` which is indeed our expected result, and this not only works because we're multiplying by one but because of the `commutative property of multiplication`. That's basically what

```
1. we can make use of the product of all the numbers to the left and all the numbers to the right of the index.*

2. Multiplying these two individual products would give us the desired result as well
```

means.

It can become a lot more clear with bigger arrays, for example `[3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 8, 9, 2, 7]` if we were to get the output for index `3` then we could do multiply all of those to the left `3 * 2 * 4 = 24` and then multiply it by the result of multiplying all of those to the right `5 * 8 * 9 * 2 * 7 = 5040` => `24 * 5040 = 120960`

Answer (score 0):

We'd run the product through the array twice (e.g., [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680548/given-an-array-of-numbers-return-array-of-products-of-all-other-numbers-no-div)). Once from head to tail, then tail to head. Maybe see the video and image here in [this link](https://leetcode.com/problems/product-of-array-except-self/solution/), might help.

In Python, it would be:

```
class Solution:
    def productExceptSelf(self, nums):
        curr, res = 1, []
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            res.append(curr)
            curr *= nums[i]

        curr = 1
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):
            res[i] *= curr
            curr *= nums[i]

        return res
```

Similarly in Java,

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final int[] productExceptSelf(
        final int[] nums
    ) {
        int n = nums.length;
        int[] res = new int[n];
        
        res[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            res[i] = res[i - 1] * nums[i - 1];
        
        int right = 1;
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            res[i] *= right;
            right *= nums[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/product-of-array-except-self/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.